# mongoos - Exclude virtual schema fields with populate

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have an Item schema which has an owner property which I used to refer to User Schema.. now I'm trying to populate the owner without getting userSchema virtual fields, here are my schemas.

**User Schema**

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {type: String},
 email: {type: String},
 phoneNumber: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
   trim: true
 },
 devices: [String],
 verified: {
   phoneNumber: {
     type: Boolean,
     default: false
   }
 },
 settings: {
   showNumber: {type: Boolean},
   showEmail: {type: Boolean}
 },
 role: {
   type: String,
   enum: constants.user.roles,
   required: true,
   default: constants.user.defaultRole
 }
});

userSchema.virtual('isPhoneVerified').get(function () {
  return !!this.verified.phoneNumber;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

**Item Schema**

```
let itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  price: {type: Number},
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
    require: true
  }
});

let autoPopulate = function(next) {
   this.populate({
     path: 'owner',
    select: {name: 1, _id: 0, isPhoneVerified: 0}
   });
   next();
};

itemSchema.pre('find', autoPopulate);
itemSchema.pre('findOne', autoPopulate);

module.exports = mongoose.model('item', itemSchema);
```

so when I'm trying to exclude the `isPhoneVerified` field I got this error

`MongoError: Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.`

Can you please advice me?

**Update** 
I found a solution for this case by using `transform` property in `toJson`.

```
userSchema.set('toJson', {
  virtuals: true,
  getters: true,
  transform: function (doc, ret) {
    delete ret._id;
    delete ret.isPhoneVerified;
    return ret;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to include virtuals, you can do it without changing a schema. Just use `lean()`. This is much cleaner way because you don't have to edit your schema.

```
Model.find(query)
  .lean()
  .populate('user', 'firstName lastName')
  .then(rec => {
    // do something
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle error
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't exclude a virtual field because it doesn't make any sense because it is something related to mongoose.
What you can do is the following:

```
userSchema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: false
});
```

This way the virtuals won't get sent in the response if that is your problem.